# Performance differences between std::count and std::find

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

This might be a stupid question but I want to check a container (in this case an `std::vector` of `bool` but a broader approach would be better) to check if a value exist. As I understand both the run time `std::count` and `std::find` are linear and count might slower if the item is in the range but I think that both should be the same if the object exists, but I could see the probability that a complier could vectorize `std::count` and **therefore** making `std::count` run faster. Am I correct with the first assumption that both will run the same or is the second assumption that compliers can **vectorize `std::count`** true?

Comment: `count` returns the number of occurrences, so it always has to iterate through the whole range, while `find` can stop as soon as it finds the first occurrence. Why do you state that "both should be the same if the object exists"? Perhaps you meant to write "if the object *does not* exist"?

Comment: You should test this and see for yourself. Obviously count has to perform more operations on average.

Comment: std::find on average runs in O(n/2) time whereas std::count is O(n) always. I also wouldn't count on the optimizer being able to vectorize STL containers, although sometimes it can find such an optimization.

Comment: @MorphingDragon O(n/2) == O(n).

Comment: @Barry, oops. Wrong notation, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the item you are looking for **is** **not** in the range, both `count` and `find` will both iterate through the entire sequence, and thus both be about the same speed.

If the item you are looking **is** in the range, `find` will return once it is found.  So `find` will be faster, the closer the found element is to the front of the sequence.

In general the implementation will not "vectorize" this algorithm.  However, in the case of `std::vector<bool>`, one implementation ([libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org)) does optimize.  It optimizes both `count` *and* `find` to look at 64 bits at a time (on a 64 bit platform), and thus both of these operations will be greatly sped up vs the same operation on a `std::vector<char>`.  These optimization are described here:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/onvectorbool.html

I'm not positive (anyone please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, and I would love to be wrong), but I think libc++ is currently the only implementation to make these optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

To find an answer to this question, I've taken a look at the behavior of the two functions. From what I can find on C++ Reference the std::count function behaves like this:

```
template <class InputIterator, class T>
  typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
    count (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)
{
  typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type ret = 0;
  while (first!=last) {
    if (*first == val) ++ret;
    ++first;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

And the std::find function looks like this:

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
  InputIterator find (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)
{
  while (first!=last) {
    if (*first==val) return first;
    ++first;
  }
  return last;
}
```

This means that the std::count function will always go through the entire vector, even if there's only one value to be found. However, the std::find function actually stops when the value is found. This means that on average the std::find function will be quicker than the std::count function, if you only want to know if the vector contains a value. If you also want to know how many are found, the std::count function is the best solution, although I don't think that's your intention.

So overall this means that the std::find function will be just as quick as or faster than the std::count function.

Sources:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/